SFML Multiple drawing circles in different positions
i've been building a game in SFML C++, i created the window, created the main character, who is a green circle. Now i'm creating 5 red circles, they are the enemies. My main idea is create the 5 circles one under the other with 100.f separation, so i use a for loop, and a pos auto incremented 100 in 100 for 5 times.
    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        pos=pos+100;
        enemy.setPosition(100,pos);
        window.draw(enemy);
    }
    window.display();

window.draw(shape), shape is the main character it doesn't matter that
and the for loop, pos is auto incremented, sets the enemy y position, and draw it, 5 times
then window.display()
My problem is that the program draws the 5 circles but they disappear instantly

on a normal 60 Hz monitor, an object moving by 100 pixels per frame is moving at a speed of 6000 pixels per second, a typical 4K monitor is only 3840 pixels .... maybe  you should not move them at a speed of 100 pixels per frame ?!

See also [gamedev.se]

Ok i understand. So what would be the alternative to my program? @AhmedAEK

I founded the solution. It was storing circles in a array, iterate it, and render it.
